# How do typehint a parameter of a function in php

Tags: php, symfony, phpstan

I am having issue getting the return type for this function as I have mixed types in the switch. I have used **mixed**, it blew up. I have used **string|bool** and several type for union type.

```
* @param  $value 
* @param  string $type

public function __construct(string $type,  $value)
    {  
        $this->type    = $type;
        $this->value   = $value;
    }
```

I have tried everything but it didn't pass the CI/CD pipeline (AWS)

```
public function getValue(bool $typed = false)
    {
        if (false === $typed) {
            return $this->value;
        }

        switch ($this->type) {
            case 'boolean':
                return (bool) $this->value;
            case 'datetime':
                if (empty($this->value)) {
                    return null;
                }

                return new \DateTime($this->value);
            case 'option_tags':
                return json_decode($this->value);
            default:
                return $this->value;
        }
    }
```

**ERROR**
The following are the error

```
  Method App\Model\Resources::getValue() has no return typehint specified.  
  Parameter #1 $time of class DateTime constructor expects string, string|true given.                                 
  Parameter #1 $json of function json_decode expects string, bool|string given.
```

Comment: `public function getValue(bool $typed = false): mixed` fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern PHP you can either provide a list of all possible types:

```
// Tweak type list your exact needs
public function getValue(bool $typed = false): bool|DateTime|null
```

... or use `mixed` if the method can indeed return anything:

```
public function getValue(bool $typed = false): mixed
```

In older versions, you can only use the [`@return` tag](https://docs.phpdoc.org/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/return.html) in the docblock:

```
/**
 * @param bool $typed
 * @return mixed
 * @throws Exception
 */
```

I understand PHPStan will be happy with all options.

Answer (score 0):

This ERROR is because you didn't declare the type that you want to return from `getValue()`

This is how you declare the return type

```
public function getValue(bool $typed = false): date
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the return type to the function.

Simply to declare a return type, you need to put a `:` after the params, like this

```php
public function store(Request $request): JsonResponse
```